# Error on Hybrid Search using Azure AI Search

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-python-sdk, azure-ai-search

I've been getting the following error using python sdk and front end although I believe I have my schema set up "Searchable" correctly. Please advice, thank you.

> "The 'search' parameter requires at least 1 searchable text field in the index.\r\nParameter name: searchFields"

```html
def simple_hybrid_search():
    # [START simple_hybrid_search]
    query = "classify earthworks"

    search_client = SearchClient(endpoint, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(key))
    vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=generate_embeddings(query), k_nearest_neighbors=3, fields="vector")

    results = search_client.search(
        search_text=query,
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["metadata"],
    )

    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

```html
fields = [
    SimpleField(name="id", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True, searchable=True),
    SearchField(name="vector",type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single), searchable=True, vector_search_dimensions=1536, vector_search_profile_name="uniclass-rag-vector-config",),
    ComplexField(name="metadata", fields=[
        SearchableField(name="code", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="group", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="group_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="sub_group", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True), 
        SearchableField(name="sub_group_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="sub_object_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="object_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="classification_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/hybrid-search-overview), you can see:

> Hybrid search is a combination of full text and vector queries that execute against a search index that contains both searchable plain text content and generated embeddings.

You need a vector field for vector query and **searchable text field in index** for text query, and **not in subfields**. Both are processed parallelly and give you the output.

Your schema contains no searchable text field for `search_text`, and this is the reason you are getting the error saying `The 'search' parameter requires at least 1 searchable text field in the index`.

Also, if you observe, it runs successfully if you only give vector search because you have a vector field of type `SingleCollection` and you are passing it.

[image]

So, in your case, the solution is to create an index with a searchable field and, while doing search, give an extra parameter `search_fields` with a list of `metadata` subfields.

Below is the code to create the index.

Here, I made `id` as `Searchable`.

```py
def get_hotel_index(name: str):
    from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
        SearchIndex,
        SearchField,
        SearchFieldDataType,
        SimpleField,
        SearchableField,
        ComplexField,
        VectorSearch,
        VectorSearchProfile,
        HnswAlgorithmConfiguration,
    )
    fields = [
    SearchableField(name="id", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True, searchable=True),
    SearchField(name="vector",type=SearchFieldDataType.Collection(SearchFieldDataType.Single), searchable=True, vector_search_dimensions=1536, vector_search_profile_name="uniclass-rag-vector-config",),
    ComplexField(name="metadata", fields=[
        SearchableField(name="code", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="group", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="group_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="sub_group", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True), 
        SearchableField(name="sub_group_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="sub_object_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="object_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),
        SearchableField(name="classification_title", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, nullable=True, searchable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True, facetable=True),])]
    vector_search = VectorSearch(
        profiles=[VectorSearchProfile(name="uniclass-rag-vector-config", algorithm_configuration_name="my-algorithms-config")],
        algorithms=[HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(name="my-algorithms-config")],
    )
    return SearchIndex(name=name, fields=fields, vector_search=vector_search)
```

And code for searching.

```py
def simple_hybrid_search(query):

    search_client = SearchClient(service_endpoint, index_name, AzureKeyCredential(key))
    vector_query = VectorizedQuery(vector=get_embeddings(query), k_nearest_neighbors=3, fields="vector")

    results = search_client.search(
        search_text=query,
        search_fields=["metadata/code", "metadata/group", "metadata/group_title", "metadata/sub_group", "metadata/sub_group_title", "metadata/sub_object_title", "metadata/title", "metadata/object_title", "metadata/classification_title"],
        vector_queries=[vector_query],
        select=["metadata"],
    )

    for result in results:
        print(result)

simple_hybrid_search("Give me description 3")
```

Output:

[image]